# My ngrok Tunne Status shows reconnecting running on a custom port (4901)

Tags: flask, ngrok

I am running a ngrok on 4901 port.

I am also running a flask webserver on the same port. The idea is that I want to access my local webserver from outside world to do some app testing.

What am I missing ?

NGROK running on 4901

```
./ngrok  4901 

ngrok

Tunnel Status                 reconnecting Version                    
1.7/ Web Interface                 127.0.0.1:4040
# Conn                        0 Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms
```

FLASK:

```
python webserver.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:4901/
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jul/2016 15:16:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using ngrok version 1.7, which has now been shut down completely. Quoting from [their announcement](https://ngrok.com/sunset/1):

> As of April 4, 2016, all 1.X sessions were no longer be and service ended completely.

You should be able to upgrade to version 2.0+ and keep using it, although I haven't tried it yet myself.